# PHP Laravel curl inside foreach loop 504 gateway timeout error

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl

In my PHP Laravel code I have a foreach loop.

I initialize a variable with an model data records.

I have another function which calls to the api endpoint with curl.

```
public function call_api($param1, $param2)
{
    $endpoint = "http://apiendpoint.com/v1/datainfo=" . $param1 . "&info=" . $param2;
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: token',
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    $final_response = "";
    if ($error) {
        $final_response = "ERROR";
    } else {
        $final_response = $response;
    }
}
```

And inside my other main function:

```
public function main_function()
{
    $records = Mymodel::all();
    foreach ($records as $record_result) {
        $var_name = $record_result->name;
        $var_age = $record_result->age;
        $api_response = $this->call_api($var_name, $var_age);
        if ($api_response != null) {
            // add records to another table through a model
            $model_obj = new Othermodel;
            $model_obj->name = $var_name;
            $model_obj->info = json_encode($api_response);
            $model_obj->save();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I request this function through my route, it keeps loading for 1-2 minutes and then shows 504 Gateway timeout error.

I'm using same server's api endpoints and those are working except this. When accessing the endpoint for single result it works, when accessing through this loop this error occurs.

Comment: One thing I see, is that you are not returning your response from the call_api method. But shouldnt be related to your issue.

Comment: Also, how many calls are you making to this API? ie) what is ```count($records)```.

Comment: @Kurt Friars sorry I forgot to add the return statement when typing here. But in the original code return statement is available.

Comment: There are 300+ records

Comment: Are the responses from the API in any way effecting the response you return? If not you should create a job to handle calling the api and populating your other model.

Comment: Imagine if each call to the api only takes 1 second from request to response. That is 5 minutes you will be waiting with 300 records.

Comment: What it does mean creating a job to handle calling the API? Can you please clarify?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues

Comment: Thanks for the link